# NightmareJS create page from string

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, nightmare

Is it possible to create a page from a string of HTML, like you can with jsdom, like this:

`global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');`

instead of using the `goto` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to write to an intermediate file, Nightmare does support `file://` URIs.  For example:

```
nightmare.goto('file:///some/location/on/disk/myfile.html')
  .then( ... )
```

Nightmare does not support direct HTML injection out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid that but I guess it's the only way

Comment: Is there any way I can extend the nightmare API to pass a DOM node and render it?